# WebRequest.GetResponse locks up?

Tags: c#, .net, webresponse, getresponse, lockup

When writing the below my code locks up on GetResponse. Why?

```
        try
        {
            WebRequest myWebRequest = WebRequest.Create(strURL);
            WebResponse myWebResponse = myWebRequest.GetResponse();
            //more code here
```

Comment: No problem when trying this on http://localhost whats the URI?

Comment: There's not enough information to diagnose this. Does it lock up for you regardless of which URL you use, is it only for one URL, does it happen consistently, what happens when you try to access the URL from your browser?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

This usually happens if you've made several requests to the same host, and not disposed of the `WebResponse`.

The default connection management settings only allow 2 (or maybe 4, I can't remember) open connections to the same host at a time. If you *really* need to change this, use the [`<connectionManagement>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fb6y0fyc.aspx) app.config element - but usually you'll be fine just disposing of `WebResponse`:

```
try
{
    WebRequest myWebRequest = WebRequest.Create(strURL);
    using (WebResponse myWebResponse = myWebRequest.GetResponse())
    {
        //more code here
```

Comment: I <3 Jon Skeet that fixed the problem completely. Again i would have never to check for dispose. Thanks.

Comment: That didnt help for me. I tried the "using" approach, as well as doing a Close on the response inside the using... but still get the same problem.

Comment: My question on SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8377185/c2dm-frequent-timeouts-or-errors-when-sending-webservice-does-not-respond

Comment: @John Skeet, I have a scenario where I want to return large data as continuous stream. If I placed my return `myWebResponse.GetResponseStream()`, will it not `Close()` the stream before the entire stream is returned?... if I do not use the `using` statement,won't that that also mean that `myWebResponse` will not be properly disposed?... I know I can close the `Stream` at my calling function, but not sure what happens to the `WebResponse` object

Comment: Solved it! wrote a void method that has two `Stream` parameters, one incoming and the other being written to, as per convention for streams. Disposes nicely!