# How to use 'using' with 'out' parameter

Tags: c#, timeout, using, httpwebresponse, out

I have a method like so

```
private bool VerbMethod(string httpVerb, string methodName, string url, string command, string guid, out HttpWebResponse response)
```

I use this like this

```
  HttpWebResponse response;
  if (VerbMethod("POST", "TheMethod", "http://theurl.com", "parameter1=a", theGuid, out response))
  {
    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
    {
      string responseString = sr.ReadToEnd();
    }
```

It returns a bool to specify if the method went well, and the response is set in an out parameter to get the data.

I sometimes get a timeout, and then subsequent requests also times out. I saw this SO
[WebRequest.GetResponse locks up?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1386628/webrequest-getresponse-locks-up)

It recommonds the `using` keyword. The problem is, with the above method signature I'm not sure how to do it.

- Should I manually call dispose in a finally?
- Is there some way to still use `using` with the `out` parameter?
- Rewrite the method, so it doesn't expose the `HttpWebResponse`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> It returns a bool to specify if the method went well

That's your problem. Don't use a Boolean success value: throw an exception if something goes wrong. (Or rather, let the exception bubble up.)

Just change your method to return the response.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use `using` (without exceptions), just swap the bool and the response:

```
private HttpWebResponse VerbMethod(string httpVerb, string methodName, string url, string command, string guid, out bool canExecute);


bool canExecute = false;

using(HttpWebResponse response = VerbMethod("POST", "TheMethod", "http://theurl.com", "parameter1=a", theGuid, out canExecute))
{
  if (canExecute)
  {
    ..
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assigne default value to `out` parameter immediately in the beginning of the function, and continue use `using` as you already use it.

Answer (score 0):

you can also use

```
    HttpWebResponse response;
    if (VerbMethod("POST", "TheMethod", "http://theurl.com", "parameter1=a", theGuid, out response))
    {
        using (response)
        {
            using (System.IO.StreamReader sr = new System.IO.StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
            {
                string responseString = sr.ReadToEnd();
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add another `using` for response:

```
HttpWebResponse response; 
if (VerbMethod("POST", "TheMethod", "http://theurl.com", "parameter1=a", theGuid,
   out response)) 
{ 
  using(response)
  {
    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream())) 
    { 
      string responseString = sr.ReadToEnd(); 
    } 
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You *can* do this:

```
private bool VerbMethod(string httpVerb, string methodName, string url, 
  string command, string guid, out HttpWebResponse response) {}

HttpWebResponse response = null;

if(VerbMethod(httpVerb, methodName, url, command, guid, out response) {
  using(response)
  {
    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream())) {
    }
  }
}
```

The `using` statement doesn't require that the expression(s) within it is/are `new` objects or method returns - any expression will do.

However - generally a request doesn't fire until you call `GetResponseStream()` so I can't see that your `bool` return is actually doing anything other than confirming that an object has been created - and there's no point in unit testing the runtime(!).  Therefore the best thing is to make the method return the response and put that in the `using` instead.  I can see from the other answers that I'm not alone in this.

That same argument, however, could be used to justify just making the change I list above.